# Count the amount of active tasks / threads existing at the current moment in my app

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

In my application (C#), I create lots of tasks / threads using:

```
Task.Run(() =>
```

Or

```
new Thread
```

At some point, after my app runs for a while, things are done with a great delay.

I suspect it's because I have too many active threads / tasks in my application, so requesting the creation of new tasks / threads in my application might be delayed.

**How can I check how many tasks / threads (created with the mentioned syntax) are there at the current moment in my app?**

With that, I want to check if indeed the counter of active threads / tasks is increased as the app keeps running.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Does this window show also active tasks or only active threads?

Comment: The Tasks window resembles the Threads window, except that it shows information about System.Threading.Tasks.Task https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-tasks-window?view=vs-2017